# How to access component Controller from outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm using Angular 1.5 and I have a component like this

```
        angular
        .module('appliactionModule')
        .component('umleditor', {
            bindings: {
                 ...
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/uml-editor/umleditor.html',
            controller: UmlEditorController
        });

       function UmlEditorController( ... ){ ... };
```

Then in `app/uml-editor/umleditor.html` I would like to have some javascript able to access the controller `UmlEditorController` like this:

```
<div class="editor-wrapper" id="editor">
  ...
  <script>
     // Accessing Services like this works
     var FooService = angular.element('*[ng-app]').injector().get("FooService");

     // How do I get the controller?
      controller.doSomething();

  </script>
</div>
```

How do I get a reference to my Controller from outside so that I can use it from regular JavaScript (not Angular)?

Comment: _Simple is better than complex_. use angular service instead

Comment: you want to access the controller instance or the scope? (it's sounds like you are trying to access the scope fro the existing code)

Comment: Yeah, it was a old code snipped. I will change that.
I would like to access the controller, but if only scope is accessible maybe I could build some workaround somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given there is `umleditor` component, controller instance can be retrieved with:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("editor")).controller('umleditor');
```

Or

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("editor")).isolateScope().$ctrl;
```

This is considered a bad practice and should be used in testing or as a quick fix. Generally the opposite thing has to be done, external JS code should be wrapped with Angular app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work with none of this options. They always return `undefined`. I assume that the id for `document.getElementById("editor")` is placed on the wrong element. I have added the id to my root html element in my `app/uml-editor/umleditor.html` file as described above in my question. Is that wrong?

Comment: You can debug it in console to check if it's the correct one. The element may not exist at the moment when you run this code. Unless you bundle the application with something like `gulp-angular-templatecache`, the template is loaded asynchronously and the element may appear any time. This is one of numerous reasons why it's a bad practice.